# DinkToPDF DLL not found in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, wkhtmltopdf, dinktopdf

I'm trying to make [DinkToPDF](https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf) work in Xamarin.Android, but I've added the `libwkhtmltox.so` library to the project as `AndroidNativeLibrary`, however it keeps throwing `DllNotFoundException: libwkhtmltox`.

Also, both the Core and the Android projects have installed the DinkToPDF nuget package.

In *.Droid.csproj, it's referencing the [32 bit file of the library](https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/tree/master/v0.12.4/32%20bit):

```xml
<AndroidNativeLibrary Include="lib\x86\libwkhtmltox.so" />
```

What am I missing to make DinkToPDF work in Xamarin.Android?